# Improving Quality of Bitmap for saving/sharing

Tags: android, bitmap, qr-code

I am developing an app in which I'm generating a bitmap of a QR code but there's a problem, the generated bitmap of the following QR code was of very low quality as I've improved it using the below code:

```
 private static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight, boolean isNecessaryToKeepOrig) {
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

        // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
        if(!isNecessaryToKeepOrig){
            bm.recycle();
        }
        return resizedBitmap;
    }
```

and calling the above method using this:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(getResizedBitmap(myBitmap,1000,1000,true));
```

By using the above method, quality is improved very much and I can see a very high quality QR code in the `imageView` unlike previous ones.

Then I'm saving or sharing it through below code:

1. **Sharing it through:**

   ```
   String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmm").format(new Date());
   String mImageName="QR-"+ timeStamp +".jpg";
   String bitmapPath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), myBitmap,mImageName, "QR code Generated");
   Uri bitmapUri = Uri.parse(bitmapPath);
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   intent.setType("image/jpg");
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmapUri);
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
   ```
2. **Saving it through:**

   ```
   private void storeImage(Bitmap image) {
       File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
       if (pictureFile == null) {
           Log.d(TAG,
                   "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");// e.getMessage());
           return;
       }
       try {
           FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
           image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,fos);
           fos.flush();
           fos.close();
           Toast.makeText(ImagePopUp.this,"Barcode Saved!!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
       } catch (IOException e) {
           Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
       }
   }
   private  File getOutputMediaFile(){
       File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
               + "/Pictures");
       if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
           if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
               return null;
           }
       }
       // Create a media file name
       String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmm").format(new Date());
       String mImageName="QR-"+ timeStamp +".jpg";
       File mediaFile;
       mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + mImageName);
       return mediaFile;
   }
   ```

but the image being saved or shared is of very low quality (in bits) and doesn't appear in gallery.

**Main Question**
**->** How to have a very high quality image through save/share?

and I don't know whether the method I'm using for improving bitmap's quality is the best way or not...

Comment: JPEG is a lossy image format, have you tried PNG?

Comment: @MorrisonChang I did. Didn't help much.

Comment: Okay are you sure that you are passing the correct bitmap to your save/share code as you don't appear to save it when you create your resized one for your `ImageView`?

Comment: @MorrisonChang that's a point there, thanks for pointing it out, trying...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks but it worked as pointed out by @MorrisonChang, I wasn't passing the high quality resized bitmap to save/share method.